# How to install Windows 7 on Samsung NP530U3B?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I purchased a new notebook and I'm trying to reinstall Windows. I could start the installation once via external USB DVD Drive. I deleted the old partitions and had to reboot. After that the computer will not boot from the external USB Drive. I also tried the transfer the image to USB stick. Still not working.

The drive and the usb stick are not recognized in the bios. While booting, after a really short moment the screen is full of "Missing operating system" messages, but with carriage return.

The manual is a mess (some windows software with few to no information). I found out that you can enter the boot menu while pressing F10 in the beginning, but also there the usb driver or the stick doesn't show up.

The DVD and the usb stick works on other computers.

Comment: Create a bootable DVD and then set it first in the BIOS boot setting and then try to install through it.

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention it, but of course I did that.

Comment: So what error do you get when you boot from the DVD?

Comment: It is not possible. Only ones the computer booted from the dvd. All the other times it doesn't recognize the external DVD or the usb stick. It doesn't show up in the bios or in the bootmenu of the bios.

Comment: Try to reset your BIOS to default settings may be then it get back the sequences like CD/DVD first to boot.

Comment: didn't work...more idea?

Comment: @wurlog: Is Fast BIOS Mode enabled? If so, disable it and retry.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Thanks. That was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the option

```
Fast BIOS Mode
```

in the BIOS. It was enabled (by default) which deactivated boot-from-usb support.

Comment: Hey, that's my answer :D Just kidding, glad you got it solved.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg that was a great find :P

Answer (score -1):

After disabling "Fast BIOS Mode", restart the laptop and press F10 to enter the boot device menu. Select your USB drive to boot the image from it. install Windows to hard drive instead of SSD. 
Note: make sure you use Rufus to make your pendrive bootable. and select the oftion "UEFI" from the drop down menu

Comment: How is this answer different from the current accepted answer?